# Cloudberry powershell snapin no longer working

Tags: powershell, cloudberry

After the recent Windows 10 update my powershell scripts that use the cloudberry snapin are no longer working. I've re-installed cloudberry already with no success.

Even though the snapin is showing as registered:

```
PS C:\> Get-PSsnapin -Registered


Name        : CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn
PSVersion   : 2.0
Description : CloudBerry Explorer snap-in for PowerShell
```

Powershell can't recognize the command:

```
PS C:\> $destination = Get-CloudFilesystemConnection | Select-CloudFolder 
"\\diskstation\drive1\backups\ow-data\"
Get-CloudFilesystemConnection : The term 'Get-CloudFilesystemConnection' is 
not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:16
+ $destination = Get-CloudFilesystemConnection | Select-CloudFolder "\\ ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get- 
CloudFilesystemConnection:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The snapin is also being added to the current session but still doesn't show:

```
PS C:\> Add-PSSnapin CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn
PS C:\> Get-PSsnapin

Name        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core
PSVersion   : 5.1.17134.81
Description : This Windows PowerShell snap-in contains cmdlets used to 
manage components of Windows PowerShell.
```

Comment: Does it shown when you use `Get-PSSnapin` without `-Registered`?

Comment: No, it doesn't show without the -registered

Comment: *No, it doesn't show without the -registered* That is the problem. It is only registered, but you did not add it to the current session.

Comment: The script that's running does the Add-PSSnapin in the first line.  It still doesn't show in the Get-PSsnapin without the -registered.  If I call Add-PSSnapin again in the same session I get an error that it already has been added.

Comment: Did you get any errors when adding snap-in into current session? Did you try to use `-Verbose` parameter when importing snap-in: `Add-PSSnapin CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapIn -Verbose`? Did anything get into `$Error` automatic variable?

Comment: Nothing at all output when -Verbose is used.  Nothing in the $Error variable either.  The Add seems to run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing a re-pave (via "reset") to Win10 and spent the day reinstalling apps.  The first app to install after the reset was Cloudberry and the plugin worked fine.  The O/S was admittedly a bit old in the teeth having been upgraded from 7 a couple years ago.  Thanks for your help attempts.